# TYPO3 Paginate issue with EXT: News System KEY: news VER: 2.2.1

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.1.x

I have a site, where im running TYPO3 v. 6.1 FLUID/EXTBASE.

With the Extension News System Key: news Version 2.2.1

My problem in that im running this code on my main Typoscript

```
#Paginate setup fir our list.html
plugin.tx_news {
        view {
            widget.Tx_News_ViewHelpers_Widget_PaginateViewHelper.templateRootPath = fileadmin/templates/ext/news/Templates/
        }
        settings.list.paginate {
            #Do not set the "max records displayed" in the flexform of the plugin, the pagination will disappears
            itemsPerPage = 3
            insertAbove = false
            insertBelow = TRUE
            lessPages = TRUE
            forcedNumberOfLinks = 5
            pagesBefore = 2
            pagesAfter = 2
        }
}
```

It's running fine on this page http://codem.dk/blog/ Then i have setup an extra with another layout, to run as a portfolio on this page http://codem.dk/oevelser/ Its running but i want to show 9 items, I can then on the page plugin in "Max Records/Page" set it to 9, and then its shows all 4 itams on the page, but the paginate is still showed as if there is 2 pages, how can I setup os it works as now on the BLOG-page and then on the oevelser (drills) page its showing 9 and if <9 then it don't show the paginate as now.

I have tried to move the Typoscript to the TS Page config for the 2 pages, but its not working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## Hi

I think i have fix the issue.

I added this to the TYPOSCRIPT file.

```
#Paginate setup fir our list.html
plugin.tx_news {
        view {
            widget.Tx_News_ViewHelpers_Widget_PaginateViewHelper.templateRootPath = fileadmin/templates/ext/news/Templates/
        }
        settings.list.paginate {
            #Do not set the "max records displayed" in the flexform of the plugin, the pagination will disappears
            itemsPerPage = 3
            insertAbove = false
            insertBelow = TRUE
            lessPages = TRUE
            forcedNumberOfLinks = 5
            pagesBefore = 2
            pagesAfter = 2
        }
        settings.listDrill.paginate {
            #Do not set the "max records displayed" in the flexform of the plugin, the pagination will disappears
            itemsPerPage = 9
            insertAbove = false
            insertBelow = TRUE
            lessPages = TRUE
            forcedNumberOfLinks = 5
            pagesBefore = 2
            pagesAfter = 2
        }
}
```

and then i told the news script list.html to use the paginate to use settings.listDrill.paginate and in the setup for the paginate layout i made a f:if f:then f:else for using listDrill og list.

It's working fine.